# JS loop that increments every 3 loops but the first number increases by one

Tags: javascript, loops

The pattern should be as follows

k_1_1
k_1_2
k_1_3

k_2_1
k_2_2
k_2_3

I can create the first block but cant figure out how to create a loop to keep going.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
 for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++){
    var x2 = 0; x2 <=3; x2++;
    var thisKName = "k_" + x2 + "_" + x + "<br>";
    document.write(thisKName);
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the loops:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++){
    for( var x2 = 0; x2 <=3; x2++ ){
        var thisKName = "k_" + x + "_" + x2 + "<br>";
        document.write(thisKName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple nested for-loops can be bad for performance when using larger datasets.

Comment: A simple oversight. If that's the worst thing that happens today you are a lucky human.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your counter variable outside of the for loop. Then within the for loop, have an if statement that checks if the value of `x` at that step is divisible by 3. `x % 3 = 0` means there is no remainder and divisible by 3. Increment your counter variable.

```
var i = 0;
for(var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
    if( (x - 1) % 3 == 0 ) {
        i = i + 1;
    }
    var thisKName = "k_" + x + "_" + i + "<br>";
    document.write(thisKName);
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated the function to include document.write and to avoid `i` from incrementing to 2 when `x = 3` and messing up the structure.

Comment: For completeness, you should try to add the document_write part, but I was about to post the same answer, when I saw yours. Modulus operator (`%`) is the way to go here indeed.